# symfony2 doctrine fetch while without creating complete array of results

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, csv, doctrine

I am looking to export to a csv file using doctrine.  However the data is likely to be quite large.  Therefore I dont want to ouput to the results to a complete array.  I want to traverse the results iteratively.

I have tried looking here 
[doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

**The PHP looks something like this**

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigtable");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // do code iteratively here
    }
```

Not sure how you do the same thing in doctrine for symfony2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kudos to Dirk his answer is correct.  If you want to iterat eover entity models then thats the way to go.  Sometimes you may not have a model mapped setup for the sql results you are returning.  If you want to do it over a raw sql file then this is how I did it.  I would be interested to hear more thoughts.

You pass the doctrine connection into the class via your controller

**Controller**

```
function indexAction(){
    $className = new ClassName($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());
}
```

You can then create raw sql lookup

**Entity**

```
function __construct($entity){
    $this->connection = $entity->getConnection();
}


function saveToCSV
{
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM bitTableExample ");
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        // append to csv file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[This is from the doctrine documentation about batch processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html):

```
$q = $this->_em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult AS $row) {
    // do stuff with the data in the row, $row[0] is always the object

    // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be Garbage-Collected immediately
    $this->_em->detach($row[0]);
}
```

`'select u ....`is the equivalent to your `SELECT * ...`

Comment: This will fail, you will face out of memory exception on large amount of data. You will have to disable buffered query:  $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getNativeConnection();
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bigtable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // do code iteratively here
}
```

is **Flat PHP** and symfony2/doctrine is designed to avoid it. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html